# Generating a totally unimodular matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, total-unimodularity

Is there any method to randomly generate a totally unimodular matrix?

Any algorithm or code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjacency matrix of any bipartite graph is TU. You could randomly generate bipartite graphs using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generators.html), and just take their adjacency matrices. This wouldn't be able to get any TU matrix, but would be a way to easily generate random square TU matrices of arbitrary size.

Comment: Transportation networks also have TU adjacency matrices. You could do something similar with them.